# Applying tf.nn.softmax() only to positive elements of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, conditional-statements, tensor

I tried far to long to solve this problem and did not find anything useful on the Internet so I have to ask:

Given a tensor `T`, let's say `T = tf.random_normal([100])`, I want to apply `softmax()` only to the positive elements of the tensor. Something like `T = tf.nn.softmax(T[T>0])` which of course does not work in Tensorflow.

In short: I want to compute softmax and applied only on elements `T > 0`.

How can I do that in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 4):

#### If you want softmax computed + applied only to elements T > 0:

An idea could be to create 2 partitions based on your condition (`T > 0`), apply the operation (`softmax`) to the target partition, then stitch them back together.

Something like this, using [`tf.dynamic_partition`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition) and [`tf.dynamic_stitch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_stitch):

```python
import tensorflow as tf

T = tf.random_normal(shape=(2, 3, 4))

# Creating partition based on condition:
condition_mask = tf.cast(tf.greater(T, 0.), tf.int32)
partitioned_T = tf.dynamic_partition(T, condition_mask, 2)
# Applying the operation to the target partition:
partitioned_T[1] = tf.nn.softmax(partitioned_T[1])

# Stitching back together, flattening T and its indices to make things easier::
condition_indices = tf.dynamic_partition(tf.range(tf.size(T)), tf.reshape(condition_mask, [-1]), 2)
res_T = tf.dynamic_stitch(condition_indices, partitioned_T)
res_T = tf.reshape(res_T, tf.shape(T))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    t, res = sess.run([T, res_T])
    print(t)
    # [[[-1.92647386  0.7442674   1.86053932 -0.95315439]
    #  [-0.38296485  1.19349718 -1.27562618 -0.73016083]
    #  [-0.36333972 -0.90614134 -0.15798278 -0.38928652]]
    # 
    # [[-0.42384467  0.69428021  1.94177043 -0.13672788]
    #  [-0.53473723  0.94478583 -0.52320045  0.36250541]
    #  [ 0.59011376 -0.77091616 -0.12464728  1.49722672]]]
    print(res)
    # [[[-1.92647386  0.06771058  0.20675084 -0.95315439]
    #  [-0.38296485  0.10610957 -1.27562618 -0.73016083]
    #  [-0.36333972 -0.90614134 -0.15798278 -0.38928652]]
    # 
    # [[-0.42384467  0.06440912  0.22424641 -0.13672788]
    #  [-0.53473723  0.08274478 -0.52320045  0.04622314]
    #  [ 0.05803747 -0.77091616 -0.12464728  0.14376813]]]
```

---

#### Previous answer

This answer is valid only if you want softmax to be computed over all elements of `T` but applied only to those greater than `0`.

Using [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

```python
T = tf.where(tf.greater(T, 0.), tf.nn.softmax(T), T)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Tensorflow but this is my try, based on the math formula:

```
def softmax_positiv(T):
    # softmax = tf.exp(logits) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(logits), axis)
    Tsign = tf.greater(T, 0.)
    Tpos = tf.gather(T, tf.where(Tsign))
    _reduce_sum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(Tpos))
    Tsign = tf.cast(Tsign, tf.float32)    
    Tpos = (tf.exp(T) / _reduce_sum) * Tsign
    Tneg = (Tsign - 1) * -1 * T

  return Tpos+Tneg
```

---

Updated Version(using @Aldream sugestion):

---

```
def softmax_positiv(T):
    #softmax = tf.exp(logits) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(logits), axis)
    Tsign=tf.greater(T,0)
    _reduce_sum=tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(tf.where(Tsign,T,tf.zeros(T.shape))))
    return  tf.where(Tsign, tf.exp(T) / _reduce_sum, T)
```

Comment: This is a mathematically elegant solution indeed! As a note, I'm wondering if it would be faster to replace the last lines by `T = tf.where(Tsign, tf.exp(T) / _reduce_sum, T)` or not...

Comment: Thank you!! @Aldream this answer, I don't see this use of `tf.where` 
this literally the first thing I do on tf, I'm studying on my own machine learning I've seen numpy and my approach with tensorflow was to first try to deduce without really studying it while still, challenging me to answer any question here in SO