# Applying softmax to non-zero elements in the matrix across a dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

Perhaps this is trivial, but perhaps it is not. I have spent way too much time trying to figure out how to make this work. Here is the code:

```
# batch x time x events
batch = 2
time = 3
events = 4
tensor = np.random.rand(batch, time, events)

tensor[0][0][2] = 0
tensor[0][0][3] = 0

tensor[0][1][3] = 0

tensor[0][2][1] = 0
tensor[0][2][2] = 0
tensor[0][2][3] = 0

tensor[1][0][3] = 0

non_zero = ~tf.equal(tensor, 0.)

s = tf.Session()
g = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s.run(g)

s.run(non_zero)
```

I am trying to apply `tf.nn.softmax` to the non-zero values across each of the `time` dimensions. However, when I am using `tf.boolean_mask` then it actually gathers all of the non-zero values together. That is not what I want. I want to preserve the dimensions.

Here is the screenshot of what the tensor looks like:
[image]

So `tf.nn.softmax` should be applied to only those groups and it should "put them back" into their original positions. Does anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT:**

I almost found a solution that I need, with your help guys. But I am still missing one step. Assigning the softmax across each time dimension to the non-zero values:

```
def apply_sparse_softmax(time_vector):
    non_zeros = ~tf.equal(time_vector, 0.)

    sparse_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.boolean_mask(time_vector, non_zeros))
    new_time_vector = sparse_softmax * tf.cast(non_zeros, tf.float64) # won't work because dimensions are different
    return time_vector
```

Please also note that this solution should handle the cases when you have zeros all across the time dimension. Then it should just stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out a solution from tenticon's duplicate link and his answer. Although this fails when the whole time vector is zeros. So I still need to fix that. Happy to hear your suggestions. But here is the solution:

```
def sparse_softmax(T):
    # Creating partition based on condition:
    condition_mask = tf.cast(tf.greater(T, 0.), tf.int32)
    partitioned_T = tf.dynamic_partition(T, condition_mask, 2)
    # Applying the operation to the target partition:
    partitioned_T[1] = tf.nn.softmax(partitioned_T[1])

    # Stitching back together, flattening T and its indices to make things easier::
    condition_indices = tf.dynamic_partition(tf.range(tf.size(T)), tf.reshape(condition_mask, [-1]), 2)
    res_T = tf.dynamic_stitch(condition_indices, partitioned_T)
    res_T = tf.reshape(res_T, tf.shape(T))

    return res_T

my_softmax = tf.map_fn(lambda batch: 
                       tf.map_fn(lambda time_vector: sparse_softmax(time_vector), batch, dtype=tf.float64)
                       , tensor, dtype=tf.float64)
```

Another solution I came up with that still suffers when the whole vector is zeros:

```
def softmax(tensor):
#     tensor_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=(4,))

    non_zeros = ~tf.equal(tensor, 0.)
    sparse_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.boolean_mask(tensor, non_zeros))
    sparse_softmax_shape = tf.shape(sparse_softmax)[0]
    orig_shape = tf.shape(tensor)[0]
    shape_ = orig_shape-sparse_softmax_shape
    zeros = tf.zeros(shape=shape_, dtype=tf.float64)
    new_vec = tf.concat([sparse_softmax, zeros], axis=0)

    return new_vec
```

but this does not work.... i.e. this is supposed to return zeros vector when the vector is all zeros, instead I get reshape error for some sort of an empty tensor..

```
def softmax_(tensor):

    zeros = tf.cast(tf.equal(tensor, 0.), tf.float64)
    cond_ = tf.reduce_sum(zeros)

    def true_fn():
        non_zeros = ~tf.equal(tensor, 0.)
        sparse_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.boolean_mask(tensor, non_zeros))
        sparse_softmax_shape = tf.shape(sparse_softmax)[0]
        orig_shape = tf.shape(tensor)[0]
        shape_ = orig_shape-sparse_softmax_shape
        zeros = tf.zeros(shape=shape_, dtype=tf.float64)
        new_vec = tf.concat([sparse_softmax, zeros], axis=0)

        return new_vec

    def false_fn():

        return tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(tensor), dtype=tf.float64)

    return tf.cond(tf.equal(cond_, tf.cast(tf.shape(tensor)[0], tf.float64)), false_fn, true_fn)
```

Still can't make it work for the vector of all zeros. Would be glad to hear about your solutions.

EDIT: actually the last code snippet works exactly how I want.

Answer (score 2):

possible duplicate: [Applying tf.nn.softmax() only to positive elements of a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933075/applying-tf-nn-softmax-only-to-positive-elements-of-a-tensor)

With the help of `tf.map_fn` and `tf.where`

```
session.run(tf.map_fn(
     lambda x : tf.where(x > 0, tf.nn.softmax(x,axis=2,name="pidgeon"), x), tensor))
```

---

Tested for `np.random.seed(1992)`

```
# tensor
[[[0.86018176 0.42148685 0.         0.        ]
  [0.64714    0.68271286 0.6449022  0.        ]
  [0.92037941 0.         0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.38479139 0.26825327 0.43027759 0.        ]
  [0.56077674 0.49309016 0.2433904  0.85396874]
  [0.1267429  0.1861004  0.92251748 0.67904445]]]

# result
 [[[0.34841156, 0.33845624, 0.        , 0.        ],
    [0.28155918, 0.43949257, 0.48794109, 0.        ],
    [0.37002926, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

   [[0.33727059, 0.31513436, 0.2885575 , 0.        ],
    [0.40216839, 0.39458556, 0.23936921, 0.44145382],
    [0.26056102, 0.29028008, 0.47207329, 0.37060957]]])

0.34841156 == np.exp(0.86018176) / (np.exp(0.86018176) + np.exp(0.64714) + np.exp(0.92037941))
```

Comment: almost what I need :) I needed smth like this: `np.exp(0.86018176) / (np.exp(0.86018176) + np.exp(0.4214685))`

Comment: and changing the `axis` does not solve the problem :) Perhaps I can transpose the tensor to perform the softmax along the last dimension like in your example :)

Comment: and in fact it looks like your solution does not sum to 1. across the last dimension either. For example, `0.338` + `0.439` != 1.0. So the transpose solution does not work either

Comment: and thanks for the link, but what they do there is they apply softmax across all of the batches togther, so I guess something like `map_fn`  in conjunction with their solution may work for me

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach using `numpy` and `tensorflow`:

```
> tensor 
array([[[0.2891092 , 0.76259227, 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.93660715, 0.18361367, 0.07234135, 0.        ],
        [0.23128076, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.45708066, 0.76883403, 0.7584804 , 0.        ],
        [0.51019332, 0.73361557, 0.87442305, 0.66796383],
        [0.9297317 , 0.22428208, 0.69184613, 0.06162719]]])
```

#### Find mask of non-zero elemets

```
non_zero = ~tf.equal(tensor, 0.)

# convert to numpy
with tf.Session() as sess:
    non_zero_mask = non_zero.eval()
```

#### Retrieve the non-zero values

```
non_zero_val = tensor[non_zero_mask]

> non_zero_val
array([0.2891092 , 0.76259227, 0.93660715, 0.18361367, 0.07234135,
       0.23128076, 0.45708066, 0.76883403, 0.7584804 , 0.51019332,
       0.73361557, 0.87442305, 0.66796383, 0.9297317 , 0.22428208,
       0.69184613, 0.06162719])
```

#### Apply softmax on non-zero values

```
# apply softmax
soft_max = tf.nn.softmax(non_zero_val)

# convert to numpy
with tf.Session() as sess:
    soft_max_np = soft_max.eval()

> soft_max_np
array([0.04394964, 0.07056453, 0.08397696, 0.03954934, 0.0353846 ,
       0.04148019, 0.05198816, 0.07100635, 0.07027497, 0.05482403,
       0.06854914, 0.07891397, 0.06419332, 0.08340156, 0.0411909 ,
       0.06574485, 0.0350075 ])
```

#### Update `tensor` with softmax applied to non-zero elements

```
tensor[non_zero_mask] = soft_max_np

tensor
array([[[0.04394964, 0.07056453, 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.08397696, 0.03954934, 0.0353846 , 0.        ],
        [0.04148019, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.05198816, 0.07100635, 0.07027497, 0.        ],
        [0.05482403, 0.06854914, 0.07891397, 0.06419332],
        [0.08340156, 0.0411909 , 0.06574485, 0.0350075 ]]])
```

Comment: this is not what I am trying to do. This applies softmax across all of the batches. I need to perform softmax across non-zero values across time dimension, almost what @tenticon did, but across a different dimension (he did across the events dimension)

Comment: Okay. That's simple. I'll update this later. I'm not on my PC now. On a long trip with my phone.

Comment: another thing, in your last point "Update `tensor` ... " you are using numpy indexing, this clearly, won't work in tensorflow